# EJS only outputting some parts of object…

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This one has puzzled me.

I'm passing an object into an `ejs` template; if I output that object I'm seeing what I expect:

```
{ _id: 5504a5e7ff67ac473dd7655c, code: 'GB', name: 'United Kingdom', slug: 'uk', place: 'the UK', regions: [ 'London', 'Hampshire' ] }
```

And if I output the `name` in a loop it works as I expect:

```
<%countries.forEach (function(country, index) {%>
    <li><%= country.name %></li> // Outputs 'United Kingdom'
<% }) %>
```

However if I attempt to access *anything but the name* it's outputting blank:

```
<%countries.forEach (function(country, index) {%>
    <li><%= country.code %></li> // Outputs ''
<% }) %>
```

I can't figure it out, am I doing something painfully obviously wrong, or is this as mad as I think?

Edit: `_id` will also output. So `_id` and `name` output as expected, all the others output blank when called directly.

Comment: How are you passing the data to EJS? And what does it output if you put a `console.log(country)` inside the loop?

Comment: All outputs fine! That's the crazy thing. It's fine in express when outputted to console (just being passed into the `res.render`), and the output you see above is what I get when outputting `country` directly within that `forEach`. I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Adding an edit: `_id` also outputs fine. So `_id` and `name` output, nothing else does.

Comment: How about `console.log(Object.keys(country))`, what does it print?

Comment: @victorkohl in the forEach loop itself? console.logs don't seem to be outputting for me when used in EJS. Outputting it directly gives me:  $__,isNew,errors,_maxListeners,_doc,_pres,_posts,save,_events

Comment: Ah you're right, it is in the console: [ { _id: 5504a5e7ff67ac473dd7655c,
    code: 'GB',
    name: 'United Kingdom',
    slug: 'uk',
    place: 'the UK',
    regions: [ 'London', 'Hampshire' ] } ]
[ '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_maxListeners',
  '_doc',
  '_pres',
  '_posts',
  'save',
  '_events' ]

Comment: And when using console.log to attempt to output, say `country.code`, I just see 'undefined'. :-/

Comment: Can you prepend the rest of the vars with _ and see if that does anything?

Comment: Also tried country["code"] just in case as well, but no luck.

Comment: I just posted an answer, although it's still an odd issue (from my perspective)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had made an error, although not one that I would have expected to cause this issue.

My Mongoose model for the schema being used to retrieve the country data had the wrong schema in it. It was a copy and paste job from another model and I apparently updated everything but the schema itself, importantly `name` was the only common variable between the two schemas, and so I'm guessing that's the reason why that's the only one that 'worked' (as well as _id, of course).

If anyone can tell me *why* that's the case I'd love to know, as although that's definitely the solution I have no idea why the schema would impact `ejs`'s ability to read the variable within the object, but have no issue outputting the object itself in full.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ _id: 5504a5e7ff67ac473dd7655c, code: 'GB', name: 'United Kingdom', slug: 'uk', place: 'the UK', regions: [ 'London', 'Hampshire' ] }
```

you con't loop on object

```
<%countries.forEach (function(country, index) {%>
    <li><%= country.name %></li> // Outputs 'United Kingdom'
<% }) %>
```

inside ejs view you are trying loop tour

inside of controller you have to pass to view like this

```
[{ _id: 5504a5e7ff67ac473dd7655c, code: 'GB', name: 'United Kingdom', slug: 'uk', place: 'the UK', regions: [ 'London', 'Hampshire' ] }]
```

forEach works on Arrays in javascript

Comment: The object is within the array, it's an array of objects. See my answer for what the issue was!

Comment: Reading the question though I see why that's not clear. That object is the output of `country`, not `countries`.

Comment: <li><%=  console.log("country object %s  index value %i", country,index )%></li> print the list then you can understand